# @azure/storage-blob not compatible with latest azure storage emulator

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using @azure/storage-blob version 12.14.0 and when I call this code on my local system using the latest Azure Storage Emulator 5.10, I get this error:

> RestError: The REST version of this request is not supported by this
> release of the Storage Emulator. Please upgrade the storage emulator
> to the latest version. Refer to the following URL for more
> information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=392237

```
const containerClient = blobService.getContainerClient(container);
const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(name);
const download = await blobClient.download();
```

Is there a later version of the storage emulator that will work with the azure blobClient?

Comment: Azurite
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio
is the latest successor of Azure Storage Emulator, it should be compatible with your package. I'm using it with `<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.14.1" />`

Comment: @levangode's comment should be an answer. Also, deprecation of storage emulator is mentioned in the web page error message links to

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the storage emulator and uploaded a blob inside a storage emulator container with Storage explorer and later downloaded it with Nodejs @azure/storage-blob package successfully, Refer below:-

**My Storage explorer:-**

> Reference:- [**Link1**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/storage/storage-explorer/)

[image]

> Now, ***I used the code below to download the blob with @azure/storage-blob package and by referring the code from this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs?tabs=connection-string,roles-azure-portal,sign-in-azure-cli#download-blobs).***

**Code:-**

```js
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

// Connection string for the Azure Blob Storage emulator
const connectionString = "AccountName=xxxstoreaccount1;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxtq/K1SZFPTOtr/xxxxxGMGw==;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://xxx.0.0.1:xx000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://xxx.0.0.1:xx001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://xxx.0.0.1:xx002/devstoreaccount1;";

// Name of the container where the blob is stored
const containerName = "test";

// Name of the blob to download
const blobName = "blob2.txt";

async function downloadBlob() {
  // Create a BlobServiceClient object using the connection string
  const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

  // Get a reference to the container
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

  // Get a reference to the blob
  const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);

  // Download the blob to a buffer
  const downloadResponse = await blobClient.download();
  const buffer = await streamToBuffer(downloadResponse.readableStreamBody);

  // Convert the buffer to a string
  const content = buffer.toString();

  console.log(`Downloaded blob content: ${content}`);
}

async function streamToBuffer(readableStream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
      chunks.push(data instanceof Buffer ? data : Buffer.from(data));
    });
    readableStream.on("end", () => {
      resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
    });
    readableStream.on("error", reject);
  });
}

downloadBlob();
```

**Output:-**

Blob content downloaded successfully:-

[image]

You can get the connection string of your storage emulator storage account from storage explorer by referring below:-

[image]

Make sure you reinstall the @azure/storage-blob package again and try running the code again in order to resolve your error.

You can install the @azure/storage-blob version 12.14.0 by running the command below in your terminal:-

```js
npm install @azure/storage-blob@12.14.0
```

[image]

**My @azure/storage-blob package:-**

**Command-**

```js
npm list @azure/storage-blob
```

[image]

**My package.json:-**

```json
{

"name": "pythonformrecognizer",

"version": "1.0.0",

"description": "",

"main": "storage.js",

"scripts": {

"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"

},

"keywords": [],

"author": "",

"license": "ISC",

"dependencies": {

"@azure/storage-blob": "^12.14.0"

}

}
```

**My package-lock.json:-**

```json
"node_modules/@azure/storage-blob": {

"version": "12.14.0",

"resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@azure/storage-blob/-/storage-blob-12.14.0.tgz",

"integrity": "sha512-xxxxxxF+cAMcyGLPD1P89g2M7wbEtUJWoikryxxxxx",

"dependencies": {

"@azure/abort-controller": "^1.0.0",

"@azure/core-http": "^3.0.0",

"@azure/core-lro": "^2.2.0",

"@azure/core-paging": "^1.1.1",

"@azure/core-tracing": "1.0.0-preview.13",

"@azure/logger": "^1.0.0",

"events": "^3.0.0",

"tslib": "^2.2.0"

},

"engines": {

"node": ">=14.0.0"

}
```

**My Storage explorer version number:-**

> **Reference:- [**Storage explorer download link**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/storage/storage-explorer/)**

```
Version 1.29.1
```

[image]

**My Storage emulator version:-**

> **Reference :-**  [**Storage emulator download link**](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=717179)

```
Windows Azure Storage Emulator v5.10.0.0
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the very thorough response.

I created a project using your code exaclty - just making one modification to add ""start": "node storage.js", to the scripts in the package.json file and I get the same error result in VS Code on Windows 11.
|starting the code with npm start
|
Storage Emulator is version 5.10.0.0 |
@azure/storage-blob is version 12.14.0

Comment: I put the code snippet into a folder with the package.json and here it is.  I get the error when running on Windows 11.

Comment: Here is the link to the source project:   https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmvW0E0DYMdm368w_uDipohX_Zy9cA?e=Z77Xwl